# Nasm print to next line

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I have the following program written in nasm Assembly:

```
section .text
    global _start:

_start:
    ; Input variables
    mov edx, inLen
    mov ecx, inMsg
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    mov edx, 2
    mov ecx, num1
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 3
    int 0x80

    mov edx, inLen
    mov ecx, inMsg
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    mov edx, 2
    mov ecx, num2
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 3
    int 0x80

    ; Put input values in correct registers
    mov eax, [num1]
    sub eax, '0'    ; convert char to num
    mov ebx, [num2]
    sub ebx, '0'    ; convert char to num

    ; Perform addition
    add eax, ebx
    add eax, '0'    ; convert num to char

    ; Set sum in res
    mov [res], eax

    ; Output result
    mov edx, resLen
    mov ecx, resMsg
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    mov edx, 1
    mov ecx, res
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    ; Exit program
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

    section .bss
    num1    resb 2
    num2    resb 2
    res resb 2

section .data
    inMsg db "Input number: ", 0xA, 0xD
    inLen equ $-inMsg
    resMsg db "Result: ", 0xA, 0xD
    resLen equ $-resMsg
```

When I run it the console looks like this:

```
tyler@ubuntu:~/ASM/Addition$ ./Add 
Input number: 
3
Input number: 
2
Result: 
5tyler@ubuntu:~/ASM/Addition$
```

How can I get it so the 5 will print on its own line and not have the cmd print directly after it? I.E. it should look like this:

```
tyler@ubuntu:~/ASM/Addition$ ./Add 
Input number: 
3
Input number: 
2
Result: 
5
tyler@ubuntu:~/ASM/Addition$
```

Comment: Write the character sequence `0xA, 0xD` to stdout after printing the result.

Comment: It's linux, just write `0xA`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have all the info already, you just don't see it yet:

```
resMsg db "Result: ", 0xA, 0xD
```

Do you know what this means exactly? It defines a string made of the following characters:

```
Result: XY
```

...where `X` and `Y` are actually invisible characters (with numerical values 0xA=10 and 0xD=13, also known as line feed (LF) and carriage return (CR)) which cause the output to wrap to a new line. They are specified outside of the doublequotes because of their invisible nature - you can't just include them there so you have to write their numerical values instead.

But of course you can use them alone as well:

```
newLineMsg db 0xA, 0xD
newLineLen equ $-newLineMsg
```

(`newLineLen` will be 2 of course but I left it here to keep the system the same as you currently use, for easier understanding.)

So to just output a line break without any other text (what you want to do after the `5`), you can then use:

```
mov edx, newLineLen
mov ecx, newLineMsg
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 0x80
```

...just like with `resMsg`/`resLen`.

---

However, as Jester pointed out, on Linux you should also be able to output just a single line feed (0xA) (and also remove the existing `0xD`'s from your code).

Comment: You don't need a separate newline.  Just put a label on the newline in `resMsg`.  Also worth pointing out that they should all be in the `.rodata` section.

Comment: Also, NASM (but not YASM) will process C-style `\n` inside backquoted strings, so you can use that instead of numeric values for the ASCII encoding.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I ran the following code: [](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ecba3950faa63a4fff4d4573bbc8d0d2).  I compiled it using nasm ($nasm -f elf Hello.asm
$ld -m elf_i386 -s -o Hello Hello.o
) but when I ran the script my console looks like this: tyler@ubuntu:~/ASM/HellowWorld$ ./Hello 
Hello World\ntyler@ubuntu:~/ASM/HellowWorld$.... Am I doing something wrong because it looks like c-style doesn't work?

Comment: @TylerHilbert: You probably put the string constant in double-quotes instead of back-quotes.  http://www.nasm.us/doc/.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I updated the string to double quotes (msg db "Hello World\n"), yet my console still doesn't post a new line.

Comment: @TylerHilbert: and that's the problem.  `db "Hello World", 0xA, 0x0` works, and so does `db \`Hello World\n\`, 0` in NASM only (not YASM).  Just using the numeric value of the ASCII newline is maybe clearer at this point.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Ahhh I see back-quotes not double quotes.... Thank you I got it working now.